# how to display chm file in asp.net mvc web page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to display an chm help file to the users in the web page. 
Adding a link only invokes the file to be downloaded.

How is this implemented in asp.net mvc?

Comment: Do you have the source for the chm file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to display it as an HTML page - or let the user download it and then open it.

Or save it into PDF format...  But websites don't generally open CHM files.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this direclty. You could use [an external program](http://www.gridinsoft.com/chm.php) to convert it to html and then append it to your view (or use an iframe).

Answer (score 1):

I don't thing asp.net have functionality to read chm and show them in page. you need custom library to do this thing.

you can read simiiar post https://forums.asp.net/t/1229806.aspx

Their are some software are avilaible online that make you able to convert chm to html file.

in Silverlight you can invoke it in html web-page using silverlight http://forums.silverlight.net/t/27210.aspx/1/10.

If you can reverse then take a look on http://word2chm.codeplex.com/ but it's work only word to html. you can made your own through reading it.

Answer (score 1):

CHM files are not naively understood by browsers... nor they are standard extensions to display them. Therefore if you have a ton of CHM files that you want to publish on the web without conversion (maybe legacy documentation?)... then you can choose one of the following options:

1. Decompile the CHM files. You should end up with a folder full of HTML files and other resources for each CHM file.
2. Dynamically browser the CHM files via an HTPP hanlder extension. This allow to still keep intact the CHM file while web viewers will be able to see the documentation with just a web browser. Check out this link for an example: https://github.com/mveteanu/CHMBrowser